# mingw gdb do not have layout command

Tags: gdb, mingw

I am debuging a C++ program with gdb on windows using Mingw, But when I type `layout` command in gdb interactive command line:

```
(gdb) layout asm
Undefined command: "layout".  Try "help".
```

the layout is not exists, how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that gdb TUI support was added to mingw in this pull request https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/pull/1869. Try to update to a latest version of mingw or build gdb package yourself with patches applied from https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/pull/1869/files.